# Deploy laravel and phalcon in docker

Tags: laravel, docker

When i am trying to deploy laravel application on my docker it's show me port 80 is already using.
One container is already running in my docker.

```
version: "3.1" 
services: 
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine 
    container_name: lara-api-webserver 
    working_dir: /application 
    volumes: 
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports: 
      - "9090:80" 

  php-fpm: 
    build: phpdocker/php-fpm 
    container_name: lara-api-php-fpm 
    working_dir: /application 
    volumes: 
      - .:/application 
      - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini
      - overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Comment: please put your `Dockerfile` content and command you used for creating the container

Comment: I have change port in docker-compose.yml file

Comment: This is my docker-compose.yml file
version: "3.1"
services:

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: lara-api-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "9090:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: lara-api-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

Comment: based on your `docker-compose.yml`, you can access the application on `localhost:9090`

Answer (score 0):

You can check which process is binded to the 80 port using the command:

```
lsof -i :80
```

This will show you the process ID using port 80. You can kill this process if it is not needed via `kill -9 <pid>`.

Alternatively, you can use a different host port mapping, such as `"8080:80"` and the application should be accessible from port `8080`